# track environment changes upon login

Tags: environment-variables, profile

Is there any way to track which files and which commands are executed when logging in?

I've made some changes to the `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` file but they don't seem to be picked up when I login as root (`sudo -i`) and I'm wondering which files are sourced and in what order.

What I'm looking for is something like the `set -x` command, but that only works for the current session and is not applied when changing user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will simulate login in bash:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

Comment: I also like to add line numbers: `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE:$LINE_NO> '`